# mysql WHERE IN with datetime not working

Tags: mysql, date, group-concat

Target Query to be like

```
SELECT
user_id,trk_data_identifier, trk_data_type, trk_date,sum(trk_data_frequency) as sum_data_frequency
FROM user_tracker_data 
WHERE user_id = 37557 AND
trk_date IN ('2015-10-02' , '2015-10-04', so on) 
BY trk_data_type, trk_date
ORDER BY sum_data_frequency DESC
```

Complicated Query:

```
SELECT
user_id,trk_data_identifier, trk_data_type, trk_date,sum(trk_data_frequency) as sum_data_frequency
FROM user_tracker_data 
WHERE user_id = 37557 AND
trk_date IN (   
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('\'',trk_dt.trk_date,'\''))
        FROM (
            SELECT
            trk_date
            FROM
            user_tracker_data 
            WHERE
            user_id = 37557
            GROUP BY trk_date
            ORDER BY trk_date DESC
            LIMIT 15
        ) trk_dt
    )
GROUP BY trk_data_type, trk_date
ORDER BY sum_data_frequency DESC
```

I have checked Mysql GROUP_CONCAT() and says `This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL values from a group` but I am wondering why it is not working, my subquery isn't returning the string I wanted. When run the subquery it does return value which is like this `'2015-10-30','2015-10-29','2015-10-28','2015-10-27','2015-10-26','2015-07-17','2015-07-15','2015-04-10','0000-00-00'`.

It seems it is getting the last part only which is '0000-00-00' based on the result

Any ideas what might gone wrong?

Comment: select without concating..

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri WOW that went well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not concatenate in subquery:

```
...
AND trk_date IN (SELECT trk_date
                 FROM user_tracker_data 
                 WHERE user_id = 37557
                 GROUP BY trk_date
                 ORDER BY trk_date DESC
                 LIMIT 15)
GROUP BY trk_data_type, trk_date
ORDER BY sum_data_frequency DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing the query to,

```
main query
 where
   DATE(trk_date) IN (subquery)
```